# OAuth2 server with spring boot: accessing token endpoint returns "404 NOT FOUND" for the token endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

My spring boot project uses dependency `implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server")` to develop an OAuth2 complient authorization server.

My beans configuration is this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain asSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
        .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling(
        e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(
            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")
        )
    );

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain appSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    var u1 = User.withUsername("user")
        .password("password")
        .authorities("read")
        .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(u1);
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
  }

  @Bean
  public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient r1 = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .clientId("client")
        .clientSecret("secret")
        .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
        .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
        .redirectUri("https://spring.io")
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
        .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(r1);
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kg.generateKeyPair();

    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();

    RSAKey key = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
        .privateKey(privateKey)
        .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .build();

    JWKSet set = new JWKSet(key);
    return new ImmutableJWKSet(set);
  }

}
```

When I'm running the application, I try to verify the "authorization code" grant type to get an access token. Following is what I did:

**Firstly, I access the "authorize" endpoint in order to get authorization code:**

I open browser and access url `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://spring.io`

My browser shows Spring provided user login page, I submitted username and password, after which my browser is successfully **redirected to** `https://spring.io?code=wPy5G_Fzm6HCXRwX8vLV2aBtiPC9y9nc2z0GTe8n5opT_e2GpQO40rcMCleynII4fyx6kwHtWbGnlLXOH977oCwLgzOp3kqkOyJNQXl8YJ8-VwrU5erOw-HUM34-jOda`. As you can see, the **"authorization code"** is also appended to the redirect uri.

**Then, I copy the authorization code & access the "token" endpoint:**

I open Postman, run GET request against the token endpoint `/oauth2/token` provided also the above authorization code:

`http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token?client_id=client&redirect_uri=https://spring.io&grant_type=authorization_code&code=wPy5G_Fzm6HCXRwX8vLV2aBtiPC9y9nc2z0GTe8n5opT_e2GpQO40rcMCleynII4fyx6kwHtWbGnlLXOH977oCwLgzOp3kqkOyJNQXl8YJ8-VwrU5erOw-HUM34-jOda`,

but I get response `404 NOT FOUND` for the token endpoint `"/oauth2/token"`, here is the screenshot:

[image]

**I then tried the following way to debug the above 404 issue & check whether token endpoint is really not available:**

I firstly verify the authorization endpoint `/oauth2/authorize` by accessing it without any parameter, I expect a `400 bad request` error instead of `404 Not found`. The result is as expected:

[image]

It means the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint is indeed working!

Then, I expect the token endpoint `/oauth2/token` also returns `400 bad request` when no parameter, but it still responses `404 NOT FOUND`:

[image]

This proves to me that the token endpoint `/oauth2/token` is not available...I wonder why?

Then, I check from the `.well-known` endpoint, **interestingly**, it tells me the token endpoint `/oauth2/token` should be available:

[image]

This makes me very confused now, why I get `404 NOT FOUND` for `/oauth2/token` endpoint when accessing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token endpoint `/oauth2/token` is `POST` http Method not `GET`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How can I be so stupid & being struggling with it for 2 days & it is just the wrong HTTP verb usage.